# Calculating mean square displacement using fortran

Tags: fortran

I want to calculate the mean square displacements (MSDs) for some particles in 2D space. From what I understand, the MSD is the measure of the displacements for each particle over the trajectory: I'm using the definition that <(∆r(∆t))^2> = 1/N ∑r_i^2 (∆t) where N is the number of particles.

A displacement is calculated as

x_1 = x(t_1), x_2 = x(t_1 + ∆t), ∆x_1(∆t) = x_2 - x_1

y_1 = y(t_1), y_2 = y(t_1 + ∆t), ∆y_1(∆t) = y_2 - y_1

...

x_i = x(t_i), x_i+1 = x(t_i + ∆t), ∆x_i(∆t) = x_i+1 - x_i

y_i = y(t_i), y_i+1 = y(t_i + ∆t), ∆y_i(∆t) = y_i+1 - y_i

The square displacement (∆r)^2 is the sum of the displacements in each dimension. Then the mean is taken.

How do I implement this? I tried the following, but as others have pointed out here it's not correct.

```
   PROGRAM CALC

   IMPLICIT NONE
   INTEGER :: J,N,T,NPARTICLES,NSTEPS
   REAL(8) :: SUM,DX,DY
   REAL(8),ALLOCATABLE :: X(:,:),Y(:,:)
   REAL(8),ALLOCATABLE :: MSD(:)

   ! INPUT
   NSTEPS = 101
   NPARTICLES = 500

   ALLOCATE ( X(NPARTICLES,0:NSTEPS-1) )
   ALLOCATE ( Y(NPARTICLES,0:NSTEPS-1) )
   ALLOCATE ( MSD(0:NSTEPS-1) )

   X = 0.0D0
   Y = 0.0D0
   DX = 0.0D0
   DY = 0.0D0

   OPEN(UNIT=50,FILE='TRAJECTORY',STATUS='UNKNOWN',ACTION='READ')

   DO T = 0,NSTEPS-1

      DO J = 1,NPARTICLES
         READ(50,*) X(J,T), Y(J,T)
      END DO

      SUM = 0.0D0
      MSD = 0.0D0

      DO WHILE (NSTEPS < T)
         DO N = 1,NPARTICLES
            DX = X(N,T+1) - X(N,T)
            DY = Y(N,T+1) - Y(N,T)
            SUM = SUM + (DX**2 + DY**2)
         END DO
      END DO
      MSD(T) = SUM / NPARTICLES
   END DO

   CLOSE(5)

   DEALLOCATE(X)
   DEALLOCATE(Y)

   OPEN(UNIT=60,FILE='msd.dat',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
   DO T = 0,NSTEPS-1
      WRITE(60,*) T,MSD(T)
   END DO
   CLOSE(60)

   DEALLOCATE(MSD)       

   END PROGRAM CALC
```

Comment: And I'd be worried that the loop `DO WHILE (NSTEPS > T)` doesn't have `nsteps` or `t` updated (unless something crazy is happening with `x` or `y` being functions).

Comment: @idadle please make a complete MWE of your example, compile it with boundary checking and run it. Also look at the WHILE loop as francescalus already indicated.

Comment: Don't use the unit numbers 5 and 6 for files as they are normally used for terminal input and output. Better to use the newunit function (not sure about the name) or any least unit numbers > 10 (search the forums for more information)

Comment: @albert Thank you for pointing this out. I'll correct it now.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you. I just edited my question and code. Regarding the displacement, ∆x_i(∆t) = x_i+1 - x_i, I'm not sure how to calculate it without a `DO WHILE` loop. When I change the condition to read `DO WHILE (NSTEPS < T)`, it should execute now, but the x- and y-values at the very end won't have values. I'm stuck.

Comment: NSTEPS has the value 101 and T runs from 0 to NSTEPS-1 so from 0 to 100 thus the condition NSTEPS < T is alsways false and thus the values of DX and DY are never calculated / sum is not updated etc...

Comment: Did you already run with boundary checking ? (Doesn't make sense now though due to the wrong while loop).

Comment: Step away from the keyboard !  Back away at least 3m (if in the US, your Congress authorised the use of the metric system in 1866 so please don't ask me to convert that to feet or furlongs).  Now stop and think.  Think why you are using a `do while` loop at all to iterate over fixed-size data structures.  We know you know how to use a 'normal' `do` loop, one which uses an index variable.  Think.  Don't change characters in the program as if at random; I see you changing `>` to `<` and crossing your fingers; that didn't turn out well did it ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you. Would it be a good idea then to have a statement like `DO T = 0,NSTEPS-2` instead of the `DO WHILE` loop? That seems to make more sense with what you say about fixed-size data structures.

Comment: OK, now that you *have* though about it, go back to the keyboard, code, and test your well-thought ideas.  Then, iff stuck, ask a question (or edit this one).  But, in general, and remember that I'm not as invested in your success as you are, your most recent comment suggest you are making headway.

Comment: Besides the logical errors (loop actually not looping), it seems that your code computes the average *squared displacement for one step*, averaged from 0 to T instead of the displacement for a time interval T.